# Why the value of root is printed as 0 in main function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct nodeTree { 
    int data; 
    struct nodeTree* left; 
    struct nodeTree* right; 
};

struct nodeTree* insertRoot(struct nodeTree** root, int data) { 
    if(!(*root)) { 
        struct nodeTree *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeTree));
        if(!temp) {
            exit(-1);
    } 

        temp->data = data; 
        temp->left = 0; 
        temp->right = 0; 
        (*root) = temp; 
        free(temp); 
        return *root;
    }
}



 int main() { 
    struct nodeTree *root = NULL; 
    root = insertRoot(&root,10);
    printf("%d\n",root->data);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a function to insert a value in the root of a binary tree. In my insert function I assign a temp node and after inserting the value into the temp node I assign the temp node to root and free the temp node. I understand I can directly malloc into the root variable and assign the data to it. What happens when free(temp) is called and how does it affect the root variable ?

Comment: `root->data` has undefined behaviour since `root` is an invalid pointer (it points to a deallocated part of memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `free()` `temp`, because you still point to it with `root`, they point to the same data, hence freeing `temp` does free `*root` too.

As to why it's printing `0` it's just a coincidence, because having `free()`ed `root` in the function where you allocated it, and accessing it in `main()` invokes undefined behavior, a consequence might be that `printf()` prints, `0`, which is a behavior, and since it's undefined, any other behavior is actually possible.

Comment: The thing I am not clear is that I have read everywhere that whatever you malloc should be free() ed. Using the same temp variable what would be the correct way to write code ?

Comment: @user1534214 You do need to free malloc memory of course. But only when you don't need it anymore. Clearly in this case you still need that memory so you shouldn't free it. Typically you would free the memory when that node is to be deleted/removed from the tree.